# How to disable EnableAsync for one of the executor to wait all task finish?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, future

I'm using `@EnableAsync` and `@Async` for enabling asynchronous call when submitting request to thread pool. This work well, as it doesn't block the flow at `future.get()`. Now, we added another bean `processExecutor` within `MySpringBootApplication` class. But for this we wanted to wait till it completes all the task when submitted to this executor. But actually, it continues and doesn't wait at future.get(). Can someone help me, what can I make change so that it waits for all thread to complete ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class MySpringBootApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySpringBootApplication.class);

    @Bean(name="processExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor workExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(600);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        logger.info("ThreadPoolTaskExecutor set");
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
    @Bean(name="calculateExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor calExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(600);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        logger.info("ThreadPoolTaskExecutor set");
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class,args);
 }
}
```

Following is Service class

```
@Service
public class ProcessServiceImpl implements ProcessService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessServiceImpl.class);

    @Async("processExecutor")
    @Override
    public Future<String> process() {
        logger.info("Received request to process in ProcessServiceImpl.process()");
        //API call which takes 2-3 seconds to complete

       return new AsyncResult<String>(resp.getBody().getDataId())
    }
}
```

I'm calling `future.get()` from other component class.